# i am trying to add two polynomials with different no of coefficients and have different degrees

Tags: java, polynomials

I am trying to add two polynomials with different number of coefficients and have different degrees.  I need to print the final result in ascending order of degrees.

I tried using two for loops and compare the degrees in two polynomials and if the degree is same add the coefficients. This worked in equations having same no of coefficients with similar degrees

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial second)//add function
{
    for(int i=0;i<degree.length;i++)
    {                       
        for(int j=0;j<degree.length;j++)
        {
            if(this.degree[i]==second.degree[j])
            {
                this.coeff[i]=this.coeff[i]+second.coeff[j];
            }
        }
    }

    Polynomial result=new Polynomial();
    result=this;
    return result;

}
```

Input and result:

```
poly 1:-4x1+6x4+7x3
poly 2:-6x1+2x2
expected is 10x1+2x2+7x3+6x4
actual is 10x1+6x4+7x3
```

Comment: public Polynomial add(Polynomial second)
        {
         for(int i=0;i<degree.length;i++)
         {
          for(int j=0;j<degree.length;j++)
          {
              if(this.degree[i]==second.degree[j])
              {
           this.coeff[i]=this.coeff[i]+second.coeff[j];
               }
          }
         }
         Polynomial result=new Polynomial();
         result=this;
         return result;
         
        }

Comment: Your question is not clear and can't decide whether the comment is the answer or a part of the question.  If you are looking for help please take some time to clearly state your question

Answer (score 0):

You miss a condition in you logic. You need to add the variables that do not have a match (exist in one of the polynomial). But you are adding to the first polynomial its matching of the second polynomial.

Comment: can you suggest with some code..i am not able to create that logic

Comment: You can order the two polynomials. 
Then pick the one with higher degree. 
Add the higher to the smaller with only one loop.